# it is a trigger program

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `krishna`.`tbl_venue_BEFORE_INSERT1` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_venue` FOR EACH ROW
Begin
if new.ground_name =.ground_name
then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
END IF ;
END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

I want compare new.ground_name with already existing ground name in the same table ...but I got a syntax error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only ' at line 4

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products. Pls only use the relevant product tag. Furthermore, pls share the entire error message because it will tell us where the syntax error is (although I have a hunch)

Comment: This question needs some serious editing...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is the result of `.ground_name` in the code because mysql cannot interpret it.

A broader problem is that you need to check via a `select` if the value already exists in the table. However, I would simply use a unique index on the `ground_name` field to prevent duplicate values. It is a lot simpler than writing a trigger.

Comment: please give me the query using select query

Comment: Do not use triggers for duplicate value check. Use unique index.

Comment: There is no trigger query for that. It is an index. If you do not know what a unique index is, then pls do some research.

Answer (score -1):

Given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from sports;
+------+------------+
| ID   | Sport      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | Football   |
|    2 | Basketball |
|    3 | Volleyball |
|    4 | Soccer     |
|    5 | Badminton  |
|   11 | Squash     |
+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `sandbox`.`tbl_venue_BEFORE_INSERT1` BEFORE INSERT ON `SPORTS`
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
if exists (select * from sports where sport =  new.sport) 
then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
END IF ;
END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Will throw the error on an attempted duplicate insert.
As Shadow say's this can be handled with a unique index. Note the use of if exists to check for duplicates.
As is the error message doesn't make much sense since the trigger will only fire on on an insert, if you need to check on an update then you also need to write an update trigger. You should also note that if any single insert in a bulk insert is a duplicate than all the values passed in a bulk insert will be rejected - you might want to handle this using an error log instead of a simple reject everything process.